# How to bypass an application from running before Windows 7 logon?

Tags: windows, login

I have an HDD image that was bought on eBay to do diagnostics on my car. It works perfectly and everything was fine. I got a key to register the software for the given hardware. Unfortunately, lately, the laptop that I was using for this has died. So, I moved the HDD to another laptop and the OS booted up fine for the first time, installed and updated the necessary drivers, and restarted the laptop and from then on, it started asking for a registration key for this new hardware ID. Tried contacting the seller over eBay for the past couple of months with no response.

So, my question, is there a way to bypass this registration window (screenshot below)? I can run and get into windows for the first time on my new laptop, so that is the only instance I can do something to it so that it won't ask for the key from then onwards.

[image: Registration Key Required]

Comment: Sounds like Safe Mode would get you there: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/start-your-pc-in-safe-mode-in-windows-10-92c27cff-db89-8644-1ce4-b3e5e56fe234

Comment: It is EXTREMELY UNLIKELY that that screen is before the logon screen.  That sort of code is VERY VERY difficult to write (called GINA) and the look of that dialog tells me that guy did not have the skills for that.  Are you saying that you can't get to your desktop because of the `REGISTRATION KEY REQUIRED` dialog?  Try rebooting.  If you have a login screen, hold down both shift keys as soon as you login, this should bypass the startup items long enough to figure out what is going on.

Comment: So are you asking if there is a way to hack the registration keys or simply not have that thing run?

Comment: Thanks for all your replies, tried Safe mode as well, but it is the same. As soon as the windows 7 boot screen is done and shows up Welcome and before it shows the window for login, this window appears. Tried opening Task manager, but it opens up another window of this with Task Manager icon in title bar and same message. Since I was able to get into windows without any of this for the first time, I am looking for a way to stop any or all processes that are responsible for this code to activate upon next reboot. The seller used to be responsive when I had to upgrade my laptop once before.

Comment: @kris123Berkeley - Autoruns will allow you to find the key that is responsible for starting the application when a user logs into their account

Comment: @Ramhound could you please elaborate? Is that a setting to enable in windows before reboot or a third party program? I have the image of my drive so I can try this as many times as I can to find a solution.

Comment: The application is automatically be started due to a registry key.  There is a specific location in the registry that handles the automatic startup of applications.  I am suggesting you use Autoruns, a program by Microsoft, to find the key in question.

Comment: `and before it shows the window for login` .. NO, it doesn't or your wouldn't see the taskmanager icon on the taskbar.. your machine has already logged in and your are looking at the explorer desktop.  @Ramhound, how can he run Autoruns if he can't even run task manager?  Stupid question though.. what happens when you attempt to close this dialog?

Comment: Go back to the safemode option.  Use the safemode with command prompt option.  Do it from there.  https://www.microcenter.com/tech_center/article/6935/how-to-disable-windows-startups-in-safe-mode-command-prompt

Comment: Tried Safemode with all options, it just reboots to normal boot. Especially with Safe Mode with command prompt mode, it waits for a while at loading disk.sys and then reboots. Here is how its exactly showing up https://photos.app.goo.gl/1AC7SAzKnjRDHnRS8

Comment: This software seems extremely hostile.  Have you considered just replacing it? Any event you should be able to use Autoruns during that first boot to find the key responsible for this behavior

Comment: @Ramhound tried using Autorun program to list all the services etc and tried disabling everything I think is not Microsoft related or not verified, but still upon reboot it showed up. Running out of ideas. Here is before and after disabling list of that program https://1drv.ms/u/s!AtEnXvOorHZ4srBRp51rPrBwxyL-UA?e=SbiAe6